# How can I enumerate objects in the windows system tray in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to monitor the windows system tray for icon text changes.

How can I do this in .Net preferably in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using FindWindow with "Shell_TrayWnd" and SendData in the Windows API.

To do this in C#, you'll need to P/Invoke into the Windows API.  Here is set of a [C++ sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/ShellTrayInfo.aspx) you can use to port.

Comment: Note that this is completely undocumented and will probably break between OS releases.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, of course.  To my knowledge, though, this works on XP, 2003, and Vista - haven't tried it on 2008 or Win7, though.  Spy++ works well for figuring out the names of the windows to use with FindWindow.  I don't believe there is a Windows API for this directly, though.